# LDAP - InitialDirContext creation - timeout not working

Tags: java, ldap, timeout, initial-context

I have a code implementation that uses LDAP functionality. Inorder to get values I am initially generating a InitialDirContext.
I have set a timeout value of 2 seconds for establishing connection. But I can see that the thread waits for around 20 minutes for the context to generate. Below is the code:
**Setting the timeouts** -

```
env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout", String.valueOf(2000));
env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout", String.valueOf(2000));
```

**Method to create context** -

```
DirContext getInitialDirContext(final Hashtable<String, Object> env) throws NamingException {
        final long timeinMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            return new InitialDirContext(env);
        } finally {
            LOGGER.info("Total time taken for creating the LDAP Initial Context in Millis [{}]",
                    System.currentTimeMillis() - timeinMillis);
        }
    }
```

Can anybody tell me why the timeout is not working.
As a workaround I was thinking I'll stop the execution manually once time crosses the timeout limit.
Does anyone have a better idea to handle this scenario.